# using same origin policy still Why JSON response is blank with jquery ajax on https link?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, https, jsonp, same-origin-policy

I have one HTTPS page, on that secured page I am trying to implement jquery autocomplete plugin.

My code is as follows :

```
function stateAutoComplete(id, widthParam){

widthParam = typeof widthParam !== 'undefined' ? widthParam : '188px';

jQuery( "#"+id).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: base_url+"/stateSearchJSON",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {                 
                maxRows: 10,
                startsWith: request.term
            },
            success: function( data ) {                                 

            response( jQuery.map( data.states, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        value: item.stateName,
                        label: item.stateName
                    }
                }));
                jQuery('.ui-autocomplete').css('width', widthParam);

            }
        });
    },
```

I am using same origin policy to get json response using jquery ajax call but when I see the response in firebug net tab, I get empty response and response url becomes red.

I dont know why this happening to me because I used same code on http page and it works superfine on http page then why this problem is coming on https page?

can anyone help me please?

Thanks In advance

Comment: R u getting 302 Found response in firebug?
base_url+"/stateSearchJSON - This url also should be in HTTPS.
if not its not up to the same origin policy.

Comment: @Samy yes you are right but I am aware same origin policy rules and my base_url is https.I am getting a response but its blank.
If I would hvae not followed same origin then even I wouldnt have get any blank response.

Comment: I have blank response means request is made successfully only problem is that respons is blank.

Comment: I am sure that its not same origin policy problem.I have followed it.

Comment: I am not sure. Please check the Target url functionality.Might be somewhere in your code the target URL will be redirected to normal HTTP . 
use fiddler or someother tools to analyse the redirection step by step.

Comment: I have checked that in firebug it shows me https in link

Comment: Try to access the target url directly in browser and see the response.

Comment: yes I pasted url in browser, it shows all response instead of showing required response

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23772/discussion-between-samy-and-akki)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the request is going from:
http://example.com/requestingpage.html to http://example.com/stateSearchJSON

and not:
http://example.com/requestingpage.html to https://example.com/stateSearchJSON
or
http://example.com/requestingpage.html to https://differenturl.com/stateSearchJSON

Otherwise, you would have to add a callback and use jsonp (which it looks like you are using).  If you don't need it, you may want to remove "json